# CSS: Make image fit the proper area with the absolutely positioned label on the picture

Tags: html, css

On my webpage there is an area and I'd like to add a image to it. I don't know the image's size and orientation (portrait or landscape). But I want it to fit the area as it is displayed in the picture:

[image]

So, if an image has a landscape orientation it must fill the whole width of the area. See picture 1. If the image's width is bigger that the area's width the image's width must be constrained and if its width is smaller - the image must be widened. However if the image's height is bigger than the area's one the image's height must be constrained. See picture 2. 
The similar I want for the portrait image. See picture 2.

In short, what I want can be easily done with `object-fit: contain;`.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500622944204-b135684e99fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
  <span class="label">Label</span>
</div>
```

Here is the CodePen: [see the code](https://codepen.io/iAmCurious/pen/RwPaejG)

But the problem is that I have a label to each picture and I want it to be on the top-right corner of the picture and not the area.

Is there any way to do this with CSS only?

Any help would appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you already tried, so we can help you with your question. You can refer to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to further improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the image with a div that has a `display: inline-block` rule, that will force the div to fit the image scale, then, in this div add another div for the label and position it with absolute.

```css
.cont {
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div .image-cont {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 250px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.label {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="image-cont">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-abstract-grunge-decorative-navy-260nw-539880832.jpg" />
    <div class="label">Label</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cont">
  <div class="image-cont">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1b/30/80/1b30806bed30a7d071752948d00e75f8.jpg" />
    <div class="label">Label</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of the object-fit: contain; replace it with background-size:cover in the img selector css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Wrap image and `.label` `span` with another `span` with class e.g. `.inner-wrapper` and add to its css

```
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
```

- Remove from `.wrapper` css `position: relative;` and add

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

- Replace in `.img` css `width: 100%;height: 100%;` with `max-width: 100%;max-height: 100%;`

Look in the snippet in full page mode and resize the window.

```css
.wrapper,
.wrapper200 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*position: relative;*/
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper200 {
  height: 200px;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}


/* for visual illustration */
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: dashed red 1px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heigth: 200px</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper200">
    <span class="inner-wrapper">
      <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500622944204-b135684e99fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
      <span class="label">Label</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper200">
    <span class="inner-wrapper">
      <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581622634376-ff17d073c4f7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1832&q=80" alt="">
      <span class="label">Label</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Heigth: 400px</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="inner-wrapper">
      <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500622944204-b135684e99fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
      <span class="label">Label</span>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="inner-wrapper">
      <img class="img" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581622634376-ff17d073c4f7?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1832&q=80" alt="">
      <span class="label">Label</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wonder why to copy my answer, do you have an added value in yours?

Comment: @ItayGal but I haven't. Didn't see your answer before posting. You can see I've edited the question earlier your answer, tab was opened and I answered when I had the time. Yes, the idea with inner wrapper the same. But rest is quite different. You made own layout, I modified OP's. In my solution image is on the top of wrapper, your's has some space from top. My solution handles situation when wrapper has width in %, your solution breaks layout in this case. In general I don't understand what are you talking about.

Comment: @ItayGal yes, sorry, my bad. You answered much earlier that I was talking about. But defenetely I haven't use your answer. Gap I was talking about https://i.imgur.com/SHBIADK.png if you want to continue, lets move to the chat

Comment: @ItayGal I take my sorry back. Looked your edit history and see that I was right. You deleted your original answer, posted this one only after my question edit, so OP's code already was. Now I understand how could I haven't seen your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use background-image instead of a single image

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img" style="background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500622944204-b135684e99fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80)" alt="">
  <span class="label">Label</span>
  </div>
</div>
```